# How can I talk with my acquaintance on Linux Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, chat

One of my acquaintances uses Linux Mint with the Cinnamon Desktop.

We would like to talk each other via Skype, but we realized that Skype is not supported on Linux Mint with Cinnamon Desktop. We have searched for a solution, but we found only Google+.

Does anybody know a website where we can speak to each other free (without Google+)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, what makes you think skype is not supported? While there are many good reasons not to use it, [you can install it](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) on Linux and the desktop environment you use is irrelevant. I've used it many times on Cinnamon for example.

Anyway, there are loads of alternatives out there, just search for "linux chat" on your favorite search engine. You haven't specified whether you want to chat or speak like with a phone but here are some tools that can do one or both:

- [ekiga](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fekiga.im%2F)
- [empathy](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Empathy?action=show&redirect=Empathy)
- [pidgin](https://pidgin.im/)

Answer (score 3):

Skype is compatibile with Linux Mint and Cinnamon. Download it from [skype.com](http://www.skype.com/pl/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64). Next, double-click on downloaded file.

Alternatively, use Jitsi. Download [64 bit version](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/jitsi_2.5-latest_amd64.deb) or [32 bit version](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/jitsi_2.5-latest_i386.deb) and double-click on it.

Comment: There is no `skype` package in [the Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=skype&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) (which is what Mint uses) nor the [Mint repositories](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Qiana). There used to be but no longer.

Comment: @terdon Skype is in Ubuntu Partner.

Comment: @queueoverflow oh? OK, I don't know if those work with mint though but they probably do. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably say what Jitsi is raher than linking directly to its installation packages.